# showing more context in git add

Tags: git

For example, with git-diff I can do the following to show 10 surrounding lines of context when showing the diff.

```
git diff -U10
```

Can I do something similar with git-add --patch?
Ideally I would like to to:

```
git add -p -U10
```

But I didn't find such option. Is there anything like this?

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
git -c diff.context=10 add -p
```

If this works, you can make it permanent by using:

```
git config --global diff.context 10
```

This is the only thing I can find that might work.