# git-commit -- show more lines of context

Tags: git

When doing a **git commit** git will open up $GIT_EDITOR for you to enter a commit message, with the diffs shown below.

Is there a way of configuring git so that it shows *more context* in the diffs? I'm thinking of something similar to grep's **-C** option, for showing more context in search results.

Reading [git-commit's manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) didn't enlighten me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading [showing more context in git add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21400487/showing-more-context-in-git-add) provided the solution. Run the following command to provide 5 lines of context:

```
git config --global diff.context 5
```